# How can I cover those holes in the kitchen wall without blocking the access to the water valves?

Tags: water, valve, dishwasher

would you have any ideas on how to deal with that properly? Plumbing is behind the wall and the technician (before I moved in) just opened the wall to access the water valves. So it's not possible to close the holes without interfering with the valves.

What can be done? I have cockroaches now and would want to seal the holes somehow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is some extremely ... "creative" ... plumbing there ...

Comment: @brhans sadly hahaha

Comment: If rent you should go with the valve extenders and steel wool suggested in the answers.  If you own this, it would be a good idea to break open the entire area of wall, change the plumbing so the valves are not behind the wall, and then re-plaster the wall with no holes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is to fix the leak so you don't need the plastic cup there. The wall looks like it was built/repaired with fiberglass mesh tape and joint compound so unless you want to rip it all out and redo it with drywall and extend the valves, use the same technique or use a lot of duct tape to cover the holes. You can get valve stem extenders similar to the ones shown below from Grainger to extend the handles of the valves beyond your "fixed" wall. Any valve replacements would require you to rip this stuff out but that would be true with many valve replacements. I admit that this is not a permanent fix but would keep out the cockroaches and allow you to operate the valves

[image]

Comment: Oh got it! Now I understand how it was built. Thanks a lot for explaining it to me. Yes, I gonna use this method. It will look smooth and clean!

Answer (score 2):

to make it removable for future access, stuff in some fiberglass and paint it over the paper part for aesthetic look and to allow you access to the leaking valve cup

Get fiberglass insulation batts with one sided paper then cut larger than the opening so it fits snug in it.

Comment: Nice. Good idea!

Comment: @Lou did that answer your question ?

Comment: I would do it right and change the plumbing so that the valves are outside the wall.  Once you bring short (4", 6") pipe stubs out of the wall, everything else is relatively easy.

Comment: @Ruskes Thanks yes. I gonna try the other method from Jack tho. Better to get those valves out of the wall once for all.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just trying to keep out the cockroaches, there's a very simple answer here: *steel wool.* If you pack the hole tightly with steel wool, cockroaches won't be able to get through it; at their scale, it's basically barbed wire. (You may need to use tape to hold the edges in place.)

Also, check for leaks--not just where the bucket is, but everywhere. That's probably why the cockroaches are there. A cockroach only needs about a drop of water per day, so even a tiny leak will attract them--they can even survive on the condensation that forms on pipes.